# Configure Texmacs to use Pari/GP

Tags: math, configure

I'm trying Pari/GP, a program to perform mathematical calculations.
It's powerful but its interface is very bad.  At their web site they advise to use other GUI, such as Texmacs, but they don't give much detail.
I can't get it work.

I've installed Pari and Texmacs.
From Texmacs I've tried Insert->session-> and I write Pari  or pari
but it doesn't work
it says "error, connection pari has not been declared"
I don't know where to configure it.
I've defined a environment variable PARI aiming to the PARI installation folder.
Or any other GUI?
I've also tried MathGuide but it didn't work either.

How can I configure it or run it?

regards

Comment: How is this question programming-related? What OS are you on? Can you launch pari from the command line? If so, can you do so from an arbitrary directory? Where is PARI installed? What does your `PATH` environment variable look like? Where did you “write” pari? For me this “Session” is a submenu which contains an item called “Pari”. Does your TeXmacs install include a file called `init-pari.scm`?

Comment: Hi

The problem is that I can't get that "Pari" submenu.
I'm on Windows Vista. I can launch Pari from the command line and it works well.
I've just added it to the path, now I can launch it from anywhere.
Pari is installed on  c:\Program Files\Pari-2-6-0\   
I have a file init-pari.scm   at ...\Pari-2-6-0\Texmacs\plugins\pari\progs\

Oh, wait, I've changed everything to look like you told me and now it works, now I have a submenu Pari.
Maybe it was the path variable.
Thanks
I was expecting that Texmacs has its own graph viewer but it opens MS Paint instead.

Comment: I was expecting that Texmacs has its own graph viewer but it opens MS Paint instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning the relevant part of my comment into an answer:

The Pari item in the Sessions menu is only available if pari can be launched using its bare executable name, i.e. if its executable can be found on the `PATH`. You have to include the Pari directory in the `PATH` variable for this.

Comment: And do you know how to configure Pari not to get the pictures on "Paint" but on something better to view pictures (ideally something interactive)? (maybe Gnuplot)